# How to exit a program running under a Morbo or Hypnotoad server

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite, hypnotoad, morbo

In the programs running under the Morbo (and Hypnotoad) server a call of `exit()` is silently ignored and effectively works as a return from the callback. An END block fires as usually but a program itself never exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

END {
  say "END block";
}

 Mojo::IOLoop->timer(5 => sub {
  say "Sleeping...";
  sleep 15;
  say "Before...";
  exit(1);
  say "Never seen";
});

app->start;
```

---

```
$ morbo test.pl
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
Sleeping...
Before...
END block
^C
```

Comment: The program does exit. It's `morbo` that's still running.

Comment: ...so you're asking how to kill the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

When *starting* a Mojolicious-app something bad could happen (no database-connection). I decided to change the root-URL of my app.

In Myapp.pm:

```
sub startup {
    my $app = shift;
    $app->plugin('Config');
    ...
    my $r = $app->routes;
    $r->get('/')->to('root#index')->name('root');

    eval {
        $app->check_important_things_which_can_die;
    };
    if ($@) {
       $r->find('root')->remove;
       $r->get('/')->to('Error::Root#index')->name('error_root');
    }
```

I don't know wether this works in a running application after routing has been used.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a `kill` to the [parent process ID](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getppid.html) from within your Handler:

```
system "kill -s INT " . getppid();
```

This will gracefully exit the server process, killing any workers that have been launched. Also works for Hypnotoad.